# How to use Selenium (java) to draw polygon using leaflet.draw on leaflet map?

Tags: java, selenium, leaflet, leaflet.draw

Sorry, but I still know too little about Selenium and Java.
When I manually draw polygon using leaflet.draw I end up having something like this:

```html
<div class="leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-div-icon leaflet-editing-icon leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-clickable leaflet-marker-draggable" 
     tabindex="0" 
     style="margin-left: -4px; margin-top: -4px; width: 8px; height: 8px; transform: translate3d(421px, 270px, 0px); z-index: 270;">
</div>
```

I would like to draw it automatically using Selenium.
I seek answers but did not find a satisfactory. Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to draw automaticly, it implies you've already got al the coordinates for the polygon. In that case you don't even need leaflet.draw and can suffice with just initializing a `L.Polygon` and add it to the map

Comment: Can you write an example?

Comment: No sorry, was commenting in general, i've got no experience with using Leaflet on Java. Perhaps you can edit your question and share some code as to what you've tried so far. And FYI the HTML you posted has completely nothing to do with a Leaflet polygon

Comment: I just want to draw something like this and I don't know how.

Comment: I understand. Good luck but i'm thinking you're not going to get any answers like this. Stackoverflow is for helping people with programming problems. Is not a drivethrough for obtaining code. Effort on the part of the questionposter is expected. I'm missing that in your question. What have researched? What did you find? What have you tried? What problems did arise? Did you get any errors?  "I want a Leaflet Polygon in Java/Selenium and i don't know how" is lacking all of the before mentioned. I suggest you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok but I've never been in contact with the leaflet and I have no idea how to do it. I had hopes for some hints.